# Trigger Alert When Slider Moves Left A Certain Amount

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, alert, setinterval

So, I am going to actually kill two birds with one stone. First off, I am trying to trigger an alert once the slider moves left to a specific degree. For example, once it goes to, let’s say, the 3rd slide I would like for it to trigger an alert. Also, I need help with the cycling of the slider. I want the slider to cycle like a rotation (360), but instead at the end of the cycle it slides all the way back to the start. View the Codepen to have a better understanding of what I mean. Thank you for your time. Your help is much appreciated.

[Live Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ragMjW)

```
var W = $('#image_rotator').width(),
N = $('#slider .slide').length,
C = 0,
intv;

if (N <= 1) $('#left, #right').hide();
$('#slider').width(W * N);

$('#left, #right').click(function() {
C = (this.id == 'right' ? ++C : --C) < 0 ? N - 1 : C % N;
$('#slider').stop().animate({
left: -C * W
}, 300);
});

function setResetInterval(e) {

var intv = $("#slider");
if (e) {
timer = setInterval(function() {
$('#right').click();
}, 1000);
} else {
clearInterval(timer);
}

$('#slider').click(function() {
var x = $('#slider').offset();
alert("Top: " + x.top + " Left: " + x.left);
});
}

$("#btn").click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
setResetInterval(true);
});
$("#btn2").click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
setResetInterval(false);
});
$('#slider').hover(function(e) {
return e.type == 'mouseenter' ? setResetInterval(false) : setResetInterval(true);
});
```

Comment: Full disclosure: It's late and I'm not sure I fully understand your code. With that out of the way, couldn't you just duplicate the first image at the end of the gallery, and then snap (without .animate) to the first one once the slide animation to the last image finishes?

Comment: Basically how the code works is the slider is literally moving left at an interval. One could see this by using the browser "inspect element". As far as the duplicating and snapping process you've suggested, I am not sure if I understand it fully. Perhaps you can explain further tomorrow, in the day? But thank you for your response. I will diffidently look further into it.

Comment: I got both things you wanted working, and posted my code down below. Feel free to add a comment on it if you have any questions, etc, and I'll look at it in the morning.

Comment: Hey, if you do not mind may you please help me with one more thing. I am trying to auto start the slider and for some reason my methods are not working? Thanks.

Comment: Try adding `$(document).ready(function(){$("#btn").click();});` to the bottom of your code. This will trigger the Start button's click function as soon as the document has loaded. You can hide the buttons with CSS `display:none;`, if you wish, and it should still function as intended.

Comment: I have truly learned so much from you. Thank you! I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This accomplishes both of the things that you wanted using the optional callback parameter in the `animate` function. It checks first to see if the variable C (the 0-based index of the current slide) is equal to 2 (3 in 1-based indexing), and shows an alert if it is. Then it checks to see if C is equal to 10 (which would mean that the slide currently being shown is the 9th one; The 9th image is just a duplicate of the 1st one) If it is on the 9th one, then jump back to the first one and trigger `$("#right").click();`.

```
$('#left, #right').click(function() {
    C = (this.id == 'right' ? ++C : --C) < 0 ? N - 1 : C % N;
    $('#slider').stop().animate({
        left: -C * W
    }, 300, function() {
        if (C == 2){alert("3rd");}
        if (C == 10) {
            $('#slider').css("left", "0");
            $('#right').click();
        }
    });
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/IronFlare/wnrmp3n4/) (Because CodePen's layout is weird to me)

Comment: Whoa, This is great! Thank you. You are very helpful. I will definitely keep in touch with you. Thanks again!

Comment: I hate to bother you again IronFlare, but I have one last question. It is all a learning process. If you see my Slider you will notice that when your mouse enters the slider, the Slider pauses. And when the mouse leaves the slider, the Slider starts again. Now, I would like to disable this function when the user stops the slider (via clicking the stop button). Then when the user starts the Slider (via the Start button) this Mouse-enter function is enable again.

Comment: For some reason the auto start [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/44mw4cpb/) does not work so here is the [Codepen](http://codepen.io/Golden/pen/dPEvmK)

Comment: P.s I fixed [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wnrmp3n4/2/) but still the auto start function does not work in jsfiddle.

Comment: This is working: http://jsfiddle.net/IronFlare/wnrmp3n4/3/. When the start button is clicked, it sets the variable S to 0, and when the stop button is clicked it sets it to 1. When the mouse enters or leaves, in addition to checking the type of event, the script now also checks to see whether S is false. If S is true, then the stop button has been clicked, and the slider should not start again. When the start button is clicked, the hover function works normally. `$('#slider').hover(function(e) { return (e.type == 'mouseleave' && S != 1)? setResetInterval(true) : setResetInterval(false); });`

Comment: Wow, you are extremely good at Jquery, while I am a novice to Jquery. I am definitely learning so much about Jquery. If you do not mind me asking, out of curiosity, where did you acquire such skill? Like are you self educated or did you study at an institution. And thank you for your help in giving me a better understanding of Jquery.

Comment: My knowlege of jQuery is almost-entrely self-taught. I use online resources for things when I don't fully understand them, and using that strategy I have managed to develop a pretty good understanding of the language. I recommend https://learn.jquery.com/, http://www.w3schools.com/jquery, and http://www.codecademy.com/tracks/jquery (in order of preference) as resources for learning jQuery. CodeAcademy and W3S also have units on JavaScript if you want to refine your skill in that. JavaScript is undoubtedly a prerequisite to learning jQuery. Thank you for the compliment; I'm glad I could help!

Comment: Hey, can you help me to a solution?

Comment: @user3308895 What do you need help with?

Comment: I have almost completed the slider. It is fully functional. So, basically I would like the mouse-over function of the slider to be void until the user clicks the Un-Mute Button (Play Youtube Button) and then clicks the Mute Button (Pause YT Button). If you go to the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Kamari/Lod1fz4f/3/) you will see that, upon load, if your mouse hovers over the slider and then hover out ... the slider moves (After 6 sec), but I do not want the slider to start until the user starts the Youtube video. Also, I just wanted you to review my coding and see if I have any errors. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry for the relative lateness of my reply. If I am understanding correctly, you want the hover function to be disabled until the user clicks the play button and then the pause button. Is that correct?

Comment: It is absolutely fine. And Yes.

Comment: I tinkered with this for a while, but honestly I'm not quite sure how to accomplish what you are looking for. I think it would be better if you started a new question with this new goal specifically in mind. Now that this question is closed, no one else will pay any attention to it. By starting a new issue, not only will you have more people looking at your question, but you will also have people that are more experienced and more capable of answering the question. I'm very glad I could help with the initial question, but, regretfully, I must say that this is a little out of my reach.

Comment: One quick note, though: You don't have to make multiple click events for each item; you can perform multiple actions in one `$("#id").click();` event. Thanks for using SO, and good luck solving your problem!

Comment: Thanks for trying. I will definitely take your advice.