# JQuery Slider Help - Mouse-Over event solution

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slider, jsfiddle

So, what I am seeking is simple in context, but challenging to implement.

I want the hover function to be disabled until the user clicks the play button and then the pause button.

So, basically I would like the mouse-over function of the slider to be void until the user clicks the Un-Mute Button (Play Youtube Button) and then clicks the Mute Button (Pause YT Button). If you go to the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Kamari/Lod1fz4f/3/) you will see that, upon load, if your mouse hovers over the slider and then hovers out ... the slider moves (After 6 sec). I do not want the slider to start until the user starts the Youtube video.

```
var W = $('#image_rotator').width(),
N = $('#slider .slide').length,
C = 0,
S = 0,
intv;

if (N <= 1) $('#left, #right').hide();
$('#slider').width(W * N);

$('#left, #right').click(function () {
C = (this.id == 'right' ? ++C : --C) < 0 ? N - 1 : C % N;
$('#slider').stop().animate({
    left: -C * W
}, 300, function () {
    if (C == 0) {
        $('#playiunmute').show();
    }
    if (C == 1) {
        $('#left').show();
    }
    if (C == 1) {
        $('#right').show();
    }
    if (C == 1) {
        $('#playiunmute').hide();
    }
    if (C == 10) {
        $('#slider').css("left", "0");
        $('#right').click();
    }
});
});


function setResetInterval(e) {

var intv = $("#slider");
if (e) {
    timer = setInterval(function () {
        $('#right').click();
    }, 6000);
 } else {
    clearInterval(timer);
 }
 }


 $("#imute").click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  setResetInterval(true);
  S = 0;
 });
 $("#iunmute").click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  setResetInterval(false);
  S = 1;
});
$("#playiunmute").click(function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
setResetInterval(false);
S = 1;
});
$('#slider, #left, #right, #playiunmute').hover(function (e) {
    return (e.type == 'mouseleave' && S != 1) ? setResetInterval(true) :    setResetInterval(false);
});


 var tag = document.createElement('script');
 tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
 var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
 firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

 var player;

 function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
 player = new YT.Player('player', {
    height: '460',
    width: '1190',
    controls: 1,
    videoId: 'kDUERmuuogo',
    playerVars: {
        controls: 0,
        showinfo: 0,
        modestbranding: 1,
        wmode: "opaque",
        rel: 0
    },
    events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady
    }
 });
 }

function onPlayerReady(event) {
player.mute();
event.target.playVideo();
event.target.setPlaybackQuality("hd720");
}



document.getElementById('iunmute').onclick = function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
(player.isMuted()) ? player.unMute() : player.mute();
player.playVideo();
player.seekTo(0);
};

document.getElementById('imute').onclick = function (e) {
player.mute();
player.pauseVideo();
};

document.getElementById('playiunmute').onclick = function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
(player.isMuted()) ? player.unMute() : player.mute();
player.playVideo();
};

$('#iunmute').click(function () {
$('#imute').show();
});
$('#iunmute').click(function () {
$('#iunmute').hide();
});
$('#imute').click(function () {
$('#playiunmute').show();
});
$('#imute').click(function () {
$('#imute').hide();
});
$('#playiunmute').click(function () {
$('#imute').show();
});
$('#playiunmute').click(function () {
$('#playiunmute').hide();
});
$('#iunmute').click(function () {
$('#left').hide();
});
$('#iunmute').click(function () {
$('#right').hide();
});
$('#playiunmute').click(function () {
$('#left').hide();
});
$('#playiunmute').click(function () {
$('#right').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a feeling your initial question ([Trigger Alert When Slider Moves Left A Certain Amount](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29465242/)) was going to bug me until I figured out how to make this work, and I was right! I sat down and figured out a sort of compromise-ish solution. In order to get it to work, I had eliminate the pause button that you added in favor of the normal YouTube player controls instead, because I could attach listeners to them, which resulted in shorter and more-comprehensible code. I tested this pretty thoroughly, and it should accomplish precisely what you were looking for: When the video is paused (or muted; I wasn't sure if you wanted this functionality as well since, although you compared your mute button to YouTube's play/pause buttons in the question, it *was* still a mute button.), the video will stop and the slider will advance to the next slide. When the interval (or the user manually advancing the slides) eventually causes the slider to return to the video, the video will start again from the beginning, and the interval will be cancelled, so that the only way that the player will advance past the video will be for the user to mute the video. If you don't want the video to start again from the beginning, you can remove the line `player.seekTo(0);` in the `$("#left, #right").click()` handler. If you don't want the mute button to cause the slide to change, remove the following interval function:

```
window.setInterval(function(){
if(player.isMuted()) {
    player.pauseVideo();
}}, 100);
```

As well as both `player.unMute();` lines in the `$("#left, #right").click()` handler.

Below is a portion of the code that I modified/added. I added only this portion in order to prevent my answer from becoming any longer than it had to be (it's already on the longer side as far as answers go). The full code is visible in the Fiddle.

```
function onPlayerReady() {
    player.playVideo();
    player.unMute();
    player.setPlaybackQuality("hd720");
    window.setInterval(function(){
    if(player.isMuted()) {
        player.pauseVideo();
    }}, 100);
}

function onPlayerStateChange() {
    if (player.getPlayerState() == 2) {
        $("#right").click();
    }
}
```

I hope this is what you're looking for!

http://jsfiddle.net/IronFlare/6o6kL8pf/2/

If you have any questions, feel free to add a comment to this answer.